# Tilt line according to mouse X

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a page where there is a black line in the middle of the screen, and when I move my mouse on the x-axis the line should tilt - and as time goes by it should tilt more and more, until it finally hits 90 degrees.

This is my code so far, WARNING the javascript has a while(true) loop and may cause the browser to freeze: https://jsfiddle.net/79ggc2hp/

Copy-paste of code here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>XYZ</title>
<style>
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<svg height="100%" width="100%">
    <line x1="50%" y1="50%" x2="50%" y2="90%" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:10" />
</svg>

<script>
var pressureFactor = 10;
var randomizerCorrection = 0;
var randomizer = 0;
var swingfactor = 1;
var time = 0;

var cursorX;
document.onmousemove = function(e){
    cursorX = e.clientX;
}

while (true) {
    if (randomizerCorrection < randomizer) {
        randomizerCorrection = randomizerCorrection + 0.1;
    }

    if (randomizerCorrection > randomizer) {
        randomizerCorrection = randomizerCorrection - 0.1;
    }

    var Faktor = ((cursorX / 40) - 10) + (this._rotation / pressureFactor);
    this._rotation = this._rotation + Faktor + randomizerCorrection * swingfactor;
    rotationLine = this._rotation;

    if (rotationLine > 90) {
        this._rotation = 90;
    }

    if (rotationLine < (-90)) {
        this._rotation = (-90);
    }

    pressureFactor = pressureFactor - 1;
    if (pressureFactor == 1) {
        pressureFactor = 1;
        swingfactor =+ 1;
    }
    randomizer = Math.random(5) - 2;
    time = time + 1;
}
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Things does not work properly, as you may are able to see, but I'm kind of stuck on where to fix things - as some of it are copy-paste of simple examples of various things found via Google and the

```
rotationLine = this._rotation
```

should finally rotate the line.

Answer (score 0):

That while loop has no break condition, so it will run infinitely, and nothing will ever render in the browser. You might be misunderstanding how code and rendering interact. When the javascript code finishes running, then the browser updates the frame and renders the screen. But your code never stops running. Think about it as needing to 'come up for air'. I'll leave out the lecture on other ways you could do this in multi-threaded environments, and for now just point out that you need your code to stop, let the browser render, then start your code again.

The old school way to do this would be to replace your while loop with a simple setInterval:

```
setInterval(function() {
    if (randomizerCorrection < randomizer) {
        randomizerCorrection = randomizerCorrection + 0.1;
    }

    if (randomizerCorrection > randomizer) {
        randomizerCorrection = randomizerCorrection - 0.1;
    }
    [etc...]
}, 13) // where the second argument is the number of milliseconds between calls.
```

The new school way is to use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), but I'd just play around with setInterval for now until you get used to the concepts.